# Deleting null rows from HTML table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have an HTML table that is pulling from a database. Some of the rows are coming in with the text **null** and I would like to loop through this table and delete or hide any rows that have the text **null** in them.

The first column will be the column to loop through and find the 'null' text and delete that row but I can't figure out how to do it.

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="ex-table">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <col width="120">
    <col width="120">
    <col width="120">
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#feaf3f">Item</th>
      <th bgcolor="#feaf3f">Price</th>
      <th bgcolor="#feaf3f">Sale Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr">
      <td id="Item"></td>
      <td id="Price"></td>
      <td id="salePrice"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be easier **not to query** those entries from the database in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var rowTag = document.getElementsByTagName("TD")
if(rowTag.textContent == "null"){
  rowTag.parentNode.removeChild()
}
```

Comment: its `document.getElementsByTagName`, not just `getElementsByTagName`, and it will return an collection of elements, so `rowTag.textContent` will not work

Comment: Yes i noticed a typo. And also you can customize it further, my method is just a recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you're using `<col>` tags in wrong way, you need to use `<colgroup>` as their parent and place them outside the `<thead>` tag. For removing empty rows you should use jQuery, then you need to loop through the rows and then remove it if the first column is empty using `td:first-child` selector. look at the snippet.

```js
$("#ex-table tbody tr").each(function() {
  var html = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
  if (html === 'null') {
    $(this).remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="ex-table">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="120">
    <col width="120">
    <col width="120">
  </colgroup>

  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#feaf3f">Item</th>
      <th bgcolor="#feaf3f">Price</th>
      <th bgcolor="#feaf3f">Sale Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="Item">null</td>
      <td id="Price">50</td>
      <td id="salePrice">60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr">
      <td id="Item">2</td>
      <td id="Price">60</td>
      <td id="salePrice">70</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You've forgotten to mention that above is a **jQuery** solution

Comment: However, statement that one **should use** jQuery is not exactly true, since plain JavaScript can do the job (just as easy)

Comment: I'm suggesting the better way because using jQuery, you can do many other operations that will needed for any application easily with less code

Comment: We do not know whether or not OP needs to do *many other operations* and whether or not he finds feasible to pay for that convenience with an app performance

Comment: I can't say about other things, but the solution I posted for the problem is more accurate and have less code than the pure javascript, and I'm not forcing the user to use jQuery, I've just suggested him/her to use it, if he/she has any problem with that, he/she can comment about it

Comment: The solution I've posted solves the task with a single line and does that [twice](https://jsperf.com/drop-nulls-from-the-table/1) as fast and doesn't require any extra library. I'm not arguing here about jQuery convenience, nonetheless, the cost of that convenience must be clear.

Comment: I'm also not arguing about that and I'm not saying that your answer is not correct, bu it depends totally on the user, if the user states that he/she don't want to use jQuery, then I'll edit my post according to that.

Comment: The thing is, and I don't understand this needs to be reiterated, you shouldn't be assuming the person asking the question know about JQuery, wants or is able to use it in the first place. There shouldn't be any need to defend the argument that an answer include the solution that pertains to the kind of question being asked -- "javascript", "html" and "loops". No clarification is required for every JavaScript question that the author "does not want to use JQuery" -- as much should just be assumed without explicit "jquery" tag or mention by author JQuery use is acceptable.